# Lag/errors while loading nested json comments data in angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, angularjs-ng-repeat, javascript-framework

I wrote some code using angular 1.3 to load nested comments from an api. Things load fine when there are just a few comments, however it stops halfway and I get the following error in console when there many:

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

I also get a fairly noticeable lag regardless of the amount of commentsbeing loaded.
I'm fairly new to angular and would appreciate it if someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

Below is some of my code:

```
<!-- View2.html -->

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate">

    <li ng-init="show=true">
      <span ng-click="show = !show" ng-show="show"> HIDE COMMENT </span>
      <span ng-click="show = !show" ng-show="!show"> SHOW COMMENT </span>
      <strong> posted: </strong> {{ View2.getPostAge(comment.data.created_utc * 1000) }}
      <span ng-show="show">
        {{ comment.data.body }}

        <ul ng-show="{{comment.data.replies}}" ng-repeat="comment in comment.data.replies.data.children" ng-include="'myTemplate'" class="comment-reply"></ul>
      </span>
      </li>

</script>


<div>
  <ul ng-repeat="comment in View2.postItems" ng-include="'myTemplate'">
  </ul>
</div>
```

View2.js

```
(function(){
'use strict';


var View2Ctrl = function($scope, $stateParams, $timeout, getPageJsonService){
    //console.log($stateParams.link);
    this.currentDate = (new Date).getTime();
    //
    this.sub = $stateParams.link; //passed by view1
    var parent = this;

    this.loadPage = function(){
    var self = this;

    this.sub = parent.sub;
    this.postItems = {};

    $timeout(function(){
      getPageJsonService.getPage(self.sub)
      .then(function(response){

//        self.postItems = response.data.data.children;
          self.postItems = response.data[1].data.children;
//        response.data.data.children;

        //tests
          console.log(response.data[1].data.children);
      });
    }, 10);
    };

    this.loadPage();

    this.viewComments = function(url){
    $state.go('view2', {link: (url)});
    }


    this.getPostAge = function(utc_date){
    var milliseconds = parent.currentDate - utc_date;
    var seconds = Math.round( milliseconds/1000 );
    var minutes = Math.round( seconds/60 );
    var hours = Math.round( minutes/60 );
    var days = Math.round( hours/24 );
    var months = Math.round( days/30 );
    var years = Math.round( months/12 );

    if(years != 0){
      return(years + "years ago.");

    }else if(months != 0){
        return(months + "months ago.");

      }else if(days != 0){
          return(days + "days ago.");

        }else if(hours != 0){
            return(hours + "hours ago.");

          }else if(minutes != 0){
              return(minutes + "minutes ago.");

            }else if(seconds != 0){
                return(seconds + "seconds ago.");

              }
    return("days:" + Math.round(days) + "hours:" + Math.round(hours));
  }

    //
}


angular
  .module('myApp.view2', [])

  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('view2', {
          params: {link: null},
          url: '/view2',
          templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
          controllerAs: 'View2',
          controller: 'View2Ctrl'
      })
    }])

  .controller('View2Ctrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    '$timeout',
    'getPageJsonService',
    View2Ctrl
  ]);



})();
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the attribute ng-include in the <ul> inside the template? just to see if that it is what is  causing $digest iteration

Comment: just tried it, no more digest errors. Is there a better/efficient way to load nested json child comments in that case (without causing lag as well)?

Comment: What you have done should work I don't fully understand why it does not work. The only thing I can't figure is that you a pretty deep tree or even an infinite loop I would have to see the data structure you are iterating

Comment: Yes, the errors occur only on json files which have deep trees. Here is an example:
https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/3dbz9t/our_roommates_are_finding_glitter_everywhere_we/.json

Comment: Instead of doing a template and using ng-include wrap in a directive with isolate scope. [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) explains what directives are and how can you build them